# how to binding TinyMCE (text editor for article) to Vue js in laravel?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-vue

hi in this case  blade i used 'TinyMCE' for article text edit , and 'v-model' is setting to 'textarea' tag,I want to bind the text inserted in the text editor to Vue. I used v-model but it didn't work.
in blade I used TinyMCE CDN and textarea tag binding  like this :

```
   <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>

    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#mytextarea'
        });
    </script>



                                    <textarea id="mytextarea"  v-model="ArticleBody"></textarea>
```

in  app.js :

```
createApp({

    data() {
        return {
    
            ArticleBody: ''    
        }
    },

    created: function () {

    },

    methods: {
        AddArticel:function (){
            alert( this.ArticleBody)

        },

    }
}).mount('#article')
```

But in Vue Devtools ArticleBoy is undefined !!
when remove  `id="mytextarea"` in  textarea tag everything is OK and work But i need TextEditor for Articles!
I don't want to use the vue js component. The codes are written in app.js.
please help me